# java.lang.NumberFormatException Fix? Strings in Integers

Tags: java

*homework

Using the command line command

> java *class* -add 7 8

will add all integers after "-add". But for this program, I am also suppose to print "Argument type mismatch" if anything after "-add" is not an integer.

I have this method to search a String for integers. If it finds something other than an integer, it returns false.

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return false;
}
```

Now in this method I try to use the isInteger method to look at a String in the first for loop.

```
private static void add(String[] args) {
    for (int j = 1; j < args.length; j++) {
        if (isInteger(args[j]) == false)
        System.out.println("Argument type mismatch");
    }
    if (args.length == 1)
        System.out.println("Argument count mismatch");
    else {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            result += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }  
}
```

Running the first for loop by itself produces "Argument type mismatch" perfectly fine. But when I run the whole method and type the command

> java *class* -add cat

it produces "Argument type mismatch" followed by a **java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cat"** error at the line **result += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);**

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Adding `return;` after `System.out.println("Argument type mismatch");` should solve it.

Comment: This is because you are passing 2 arguments that is -add and cat to the class. The Integer.parseInt in else throws this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the error because you don't terminate exection once you find there's a problem with the input.

Add a `return;` statement to the code the executes when there's a problem:

```
for (int j = 1; j < args.length; j++) {
    if (!isInteger(args[j])) {
        System.out.println("Argument type mismatch");
        return; // Added this line
    }
}
```

---

Also note the slight change in the `if` condition. It's better coding style to not compare with boolean literals, ie change:

```
if (isInteger(args[j]) == false)
```

to

```
if (!isInteger(args[j]))
```

The reason this is good coding practice is it prevents this happening:

```
// Oops! An assignment that compiles and executes as "true"
if (someBooleanVariable = true)
```

when you meant to code a *comparison*:

```
if (someBooleanVariable == true)
```

The visual difference is subtle, and can lead to frustrating bugs if you don't visually pick it up, but there is no chance of this problem if you code:

```
if (someBooleanVariable)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the if condition. Better to stop coding like this right when I'm in the learning process.

Comment: @Jerry yeah - see edit to answer for why it's not good practice

Comment: Actually by doing this, the command **java *class* -add 5 4** will no longer print anything when it should print 9.

Comment: @Jerry huh? Note the opening brace after the `if` and the close brace after the return. Have you got those in?

Comment: I did not nice catch.

Answer (score 2):

It prints `Argument type mismatch`, but you do not end your program. You can add a `return` statement as @Bohemian suggested or you can use a if structure like below. I personally don't like `return` statement in a middle of a function. Choose a solution that fits you :)

Try something like this:

```
private static void add(String[] args) 
{
    if (args.length <= 1) // Validate number of arguments
    {
        System.out.println("Argument count mismatch");
    }
    else // Number of arguments valid
    {
        // Validate that we received only numbers
        boolean allIntegerValid = true;

        for (int j = 1; j < args.length; j++) 
        {
            allIntegerValid = allIntegerValid && isInteger(args[j]);
        }

        if (allIntegerValid) // We received only numbers
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) 
            {
                result += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        else // At least one argument was not a number
        {
            System.out.println("Argument type mismatch");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I +1 you, but it would be nice if you do not give the code answer away :)